# AX2012 Is it possible to access the Call Context from inside a Custom Service Operation?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, aif

I have a Custom Inbound AIF Service in Dynamics AX 2012. I'd like to access to the MessageID inside my Custom Service Operation. Is it possible to access the Call Context object from inside my Custom Service Operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, this isn't possible.

You can modify the AifDispatcher.callServiceMethod method to achieve this though. For example by saving it to a table and passing the RecId to your service class. Or passing the (a copy of) context as another parameter. Both options aren't very clean though.